# angular-slider not being updated on size change

Tags: angularjs

**Problem Description:**
Two divs are changed by their width. **Div#1** gets bigger, **Div#2** gets smaller.
**Div#2** is a container for angular-slider. The container is being updated, but the slider remains the old size **UNTIL** you change one bubble of the slider

> [see this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCUHHTkST8ZO3G2MOmhp?p=preview)

Any ideas why this is only happening when interacting with the slider?

----**UPDATE**-----

I edited the example to have a **directive called width-watcher**. It is watching the width of **Div#2** and just doing a console.log. Same problem here. Only when changing one bubble of the slider the message gets logged.

How to listen to size changes? And why are the only happening when the slider is updated?

See here:

> [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OVZgxEgZKZg3tZ9nGn76?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem is waiting for the animation to end.

That is, using the **CSS Event [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/transitionend)** . So registering this:

```
post: function(scope, element, attributes) {
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('rightPanel')).on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
          function() {
           console.log('animation ended');
           updateDOM();
          });
```

results in a **correct way of updating the DOM** as soon as the animation has ended.
Therefore the **width-watcher** directive is never used and has been removed.

Updated Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OVZgxEgZKZg3tZ9nGn76?p=preview